# swap columns in a 3*4 matrix using java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, swap, indexoutofboundsexception

i have written a code in java to swap columns for a 3*4 matrix.

```
String[][] a = { { a,t,t,a},
                 { c,k,a,t},
                 { d,a,w,n }
               };
```

And what i want as the output is:
a,t,t,a,
t,a,k,c,
n,w,a,d.

so my loop is as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<=2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<=5;j++) {
        if(j<=2) {
            temp=a[i][j+1];
            a[i][j+1]=a[i][j];
            a[i][j]=temp;
        }
        if(j>3) {
            temp=a[i][j-3];
            a[i][j-3]=a[i][j-4];
            a[i][j-4]=temp;
        } else {
            temp=a[i][j-1];
            a[i][j-1]=a[i][j-2];
            a[i][j-2]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at Execute.swapColums(DtTwo.java:69)
at DtTwo.main(DtTwo.java:11)
```

please help..

Comment: do you want to swap the columns or reverse some rows? your desired output is strange.

Comment: If you want to understand what your code is doing and why it is not doing what you think it should, you should try your debugger first.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
public class Test
{  
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       String[][] array2d = { 
                       { "a","t","t","a"},
                       { "c","k","a","t"},
                       { "d","a","w","n" }
                     };

       for (int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
       {
           swapCols(array2d[i]);
       }

       print(array2d);
   }

   private static void swapCols(String s[])
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length / 2; i++)
       {

            String temp = s[s.length - 1 - i];
            s[s.length - 1 - i] = s[i];
            s[i] = temp;
       }
   }

   private static void print(String[][] array2d)
   {
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2d));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[[a, t, t, a], [t, a, k, c], [n, w, a, d]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swap(int[][] arr, int line, int pos1, int pos2) {
    int temp = arr[line][pos1];
    arr[line][pos1] = arr[line][pos2];
    arr[line][pos2] = temp;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
   String[][] arr = { 
                   { "a","t","t","a"},
                   { "c","k","a","t"},
                   { "d","a","w","n" }
                 };

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        swap(arr, i, 0, 3);
        swap(arr, i, 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid idea, but it could be simplified much more than now to make it more efficient to use

So the idea is, convert a row into list -> make it to -> reverse the string -> use split method to generate the array again.

```
String[][] a = {{"a", "t", "t", "a"},
            {"c", "k", "a", "t"},
            {"d", "a", "w", "n"}
        };

        System.out.println(
            new StringBuffer(Arrays.asList(a[1]).
            toString().
            replace("[", "").
            replace("]", "").
            replace(" ", "")).
            reverse().
            toString().
            split(","));
```

*result = a[1] -> t, a, k, c*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public void test() {
    String[][] a = {
            {"a", "t", "t", "a"},
            {"c", "k", "a", "t"},
            {"d", "a", "w", "n"}
    };

    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length / 2; j++) {
            tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][a.length - j];
            a[i][a.length - j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
because you have 4 columns and you loop over more columns here

```
for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
```

Try to change in

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
```